# How do you list the most complex methods of a project in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, cyclomatic-complexity

In Sonar, you can have the list of classes sorted by average complexity of methods of the class (when you list the complexity per method from the dashboard)

But how do you list the most complex methods project-wide ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, because Sonar does not keep measures at method level.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with our tool, called [SourceMeter](http://www.sourcemeter.com/) (by FrontEndART) which has a plug-in for Sonar as well. You can take a look at the [online demo interface of SourceMeter](https://sonarqube.sourcemeter.com/dashboard/index?id=JFreeChart).

Comment: The "Method Hotspots by McCabe's Cyclomatic Complexity" table is really useful.